# How to prove that if $a$, $b$, $c$, and $d$ are integers divisible by $ab-cd$, then $|ab - cd| = 1$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, divisibility

Have a very good day!

This problem was mentioned in *Mathematical Circles: (Russian Experience)* and I was trying to solve it but eventually was unavailable.

If $a,b,c$ & $d$ are integers, &

$$ab - cd \mid a, b, c, d$$

Then prove $|ab - cd|=1$

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or be closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognize and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: We have $ab-cd\mid ab$ and $ab-cd\mid cd$, which may be useful...

Comment: Please edit to include your solution, or post your solution below.

Comment: @lulu isn't the hint enough?

Comment: we should let the OP try

Comment: Thanks for letting me try, and thanks @youthdoo for the hint, I was, indeed able to solve it with the hint. Could I include my solution (not mine really, whatever) in the original post ir in an answer to my question

Comment: @youthdoo I think you must post an answer now, for completeness, since the OP has solved, as per [this](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/35479/1088689)

Comment: @MerlintheImmortal  You can certainly post your solution, giving credit to the hint as you feel appropriate.

Comment: Hint:  $\ g^2\mid ad-bc\mid g,\ $ for $\ g =\gcd(a,b,c,d)\ $

Comment: @youthdoo I tried a proof according to your hint, and found that we need to consider $ab-cd|a,b,c,d$. Only considering $ab-cd|ab$ and $ab-cd|cd$ is not enough as shown by $ab = 8,cd = 6$

Comment: @DS I'm quite sure that I didn't make any mistake before when I commented but my paper was thrown away. It's a bit late and I'll think it tomorrow... Yes, I remember that it is necessary to use all four conditions.

Comment: I am currently considering Bill's comment which seems correct, if his first statement cn be proven

Comment: The answer you accepted is essentially (a very roundabout) version of my hint (see my comment there), but instead uses  $\,g = ab-cd\,$ (using $g = $ gcd works for more general problems of this sort).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that $ab-cd\ne0$, we have the following.

From $ab-cd\mid a$, $b$, we get $ab-cd\mid ab$. Let $k(ab-cd)=ab$, where $k\in\Bbb Z$, then $(k-1)ab=kcd$. Since $(k-1,k)=1$, $k-1\mid cd$ and $k\mid ab$. Let $ab=tk$ where $t\in\Bbb Z$, so $cd=t(k-1)$, and $ab-cd=t$. Let $a=At$ and $b=Bt$ where $A$, $B\in\Bbb Z$.

By the same reason, we can let $c=Ct$ and $d=Dt$ where $C$, $D\in\Bbb Z$. Hence,
\[ABt^2-CDt^2=t\implies(AB-CD)t=1.\]
We may only have $t=\pm1$, meaning that $t=\pm1$ so $|ab-cd|=|t|=1$, as desired.

Comment: @DS I managed to recover the proof.  How about now?

Comment: are you allowed to assume both $a = At$ and $b = Bt$? It directly implies $t|k$ ....

Comment: @DS Because $t=ab-cd\mid a$ and $b$.

Comment: oh right, couldn't find any error (+1)

Comment: **Easier** $\ t:=ab\!-\!cd\mid a,b,c,d \Rightarrow tt\mid ab,cd \Rightarrow \color{#c00}{tt\mid t} \Rightarrow \color{#c00}{t =\pm1}.\ $ This is the same idea as in my [hint](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4640970/how-to-prove-that-if-a-b-c-and-d-are-integers-divisible-by-ab-cd-t#comment9795912_4640970), which shows how to do that more generally using gcds. Your first few paragraphs are unneeded.

Comment: @BillDubuque By the way, the issue of whether $0\mid0$ is still there...

Comment: Likely they are using a def'n of divisibility that excludes divisibility by $0,\,$ so the trivial solution $\,a,b,c,d=0\,$ is excluded.

Answer (score 1):

Let $p$ a prime such that $p \mid ab-cd \mid a,b,c,d$. Let $n\in \mathbb{N}$ be the largest exponent of $p$ that divides $ab-cd$. So $p^n\mid ab-cd$.
Then $p^n \mid a,b,c,d \implies p^{2n}\mid ab$.

Can you finish?

Comment: do you mean $p^{2n}$ divides $cd$ similarly hence $p^{2n}$ divides $ab-cd$, only possible if $2n=n$?

Comment: yes, well done.

Comment: ok thanks, I did not think it would be that easy (+1)

Comment: This is essentially the same as my [hint](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4640970/a-b-c-d-are-devidable-to-ab-cd#comment9795912_4640970) one hour ago (except using prime factor form of gcd)

Comment: great minds think alike